# Using the prolog format predicate to print to file

Tags: prolog

Is it possible to use the prolog `format` predicate to print to file?

I have a table of data that I print to stdout using the format predicate, i.e.

```
print_table :-
    print_table_header,
    forall(range(1.0,10.0,0.1,N), print_row(N,L)).

%% print_row(L) :- take a list of the form, [a,b,c,d,e] and
%% print it to screen as a single row of tab separated float values (1DP)
print_row(N,L) :-
    build_row(N,L),
    format('~t~1f~10+ ~t~1f~10+ ~t~1f~10+ ~t~1f~10+ ~t~1f~10+ ~n', L).

print_table_header :-
    format('~t~w~10+ ~t~w~10+ ~t~w~10+ ~t~w~10+ ~t~w~10+ ~n', ['N','N2','N3','N4','N5']).
```

would be nice to somehow reuse the code to print the same thing to file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can!

Consider the following extract of the [SICStus Prolog documentation for `format/[2,3]`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dformat.html):

> 11.3.85 format/[2,3]
>
> Synopsis
>
> format(+Control, +Arguments)
>
> format(+Stream, +Control, +Arguments)
>
> Interprets the Arguments according to the Control string and prints the result on Stream.

The predicates `format/[2,3]` are widely supported across Prolog implementations.

However, as of right now, these predicates are not part of ISO Prolog.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other good answer (+1!), I would like to present a purer solution to such tasks.

The key idea is to make `format/2` accessible within DCGs, and then to use a DCG to describe the output.

This is very easy, using the `codes` argument of `format/3`, provided by several Prolog implementations. All you need are the following short auxiliary definitions:

```
format_(Data, Args) --> call(format_dlist(Data, Args)).

format_dlist(Data, Args, Cs0, Cs) :- format(codes(Cs0,Cs), Data, Args).
```

The nonterminal `call//1` calls its argument with two additional arguments that let you access the implicit DCG arguments, and this is used to describe additional codes via `format/3`.

Now, we can simply use the nonterminal `format_//2` within DCGs.

For example, to describe a simple table:

```
table -->
    row([a,b,c]),
    row([d,e,f]).

row(Ls) --> format_("~t~w~10+~t~w~10+~t~w~10+~n", Ls).
```

Usage example and result:

```
?- phrase(table, Cs), format("~s", [Cs]).
         a         b         c
         d         e         f
Cs = [32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32|...].
```

Note that one last remaining `format/2` is used to actually write the output to the screen.

However, everything else is free of side-effects and declaratively describes a table.

An important advantage of this method is that you can easily write *test cases* to see whether your tables are (still) correctly formatted. It is easy to reason about Prolog lists of codes (described with a DCG), but quite hard to reason about things that only appear on the terminal.

Comment: thanks mat - i have a feeling this is an elegant solution but i know way to little yet to comprehend it - back to the DCG section in learn prolog now! for me

Comment: Check out the [DCG tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dcg/info) for more information!

Answer (score 3):

I would write the output 'routines' with an additional parameter, a `Stream`, and then I would pass `user` while testing or printing to screen. See ISO predicates [open](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=open/3)/3, close/1 etc for stream handling...

Note that IO it's among the least 'declarative' areas of the language, because, for efficiency, an approach based on side effects is required...

SWI-Prolog has a builtin [with_output_to](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=with_output_to/2), that would allows to reuse your existing code without adding a parameter. But since you tagged [iso-prolog](/questions/tagged/iso-prolog) your question, you should really add the Stream parameter...